# calculate function in calculator not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default function App() {
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(0);
  const [storeArr, setStoreArr] = useState([]);

  function click(selector) {
    setActiveKey(selector);
    if (activeKey !== "=") {
      setStoreArr([...storeArr, selector]);
      setActiveKey(selector);
    }
  }

  function clear() {
    setStoreArr([]);
    setActiveKey(0);
  }

  function calculate(storeArr) {
    // combine consecutive numbers into a single number
    for (let i = 0; i < storeArr.length; i++) {
      if (
        typeof storeArr[i] === "number" &&
        typeof storeArr[i + 1] === "number"
      ) {
        storeArr[i] = storeArr[i] * 10 + storeArr[i + 1];
        storeArr.splice(i + 1, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }

    // perform multiplication and division first
    for (let i = 0; i < storeArr.length; i++) {
      if (storeArr[i] === "x") {
        storeArr[i - 1] = storeArr[i - 1] * storeArr[i + 1];
        storeArr.splice(i, 2);
        i--;
      } else if (storeArr[i] === "/") {
        storeArr[i - 1] = storeArr[i - 1] / storeArr[i + 1];
        storeArr.splice(i, 2);
        i--;
      }
    }

    // perform addition and subtraction
    for (let i = 0; i < storeArr.length; i++) {
      if (storeArr[i] === "+") {
        storeArr[i - 1] = storeArr[i - 1] + storeArr[i + 1];
        storeArr.splice(i, 2);
        i--;
      } else if (storeArr[i] === "-") {
        storeArr[i - 1] = storeArr[i - 1] - storeArr[i + 1];
        storeArr.splice(i, 2);
        i--;
      }
    }
    console.log(calculate(storeArr));

    // return the result
    return storeArr[0];
  }

  const topFuncs = [
    {
      name: "clear",
      text: "AC"
    },
    {
      name: "divide",
      text: "/"
    }
  ];

  const numsDiv = [
    {
      name: "seven",
      text: 7
    },
    {
      name: "eight",
      text: 8
    },
    {
      name: "nine",
      text: 9
    },
    {
      name: "four",
      text: 4
    },
    {
      name: "five",
      text: 5
    },
    {
      name: "six",
      text: 6
    },
    {
      name: "one",
      text: 1
    },
    {
      name: "two",
      text: 2
    },
    {
      name: "three",
      text: 3
    },
    {
      name: "zero",
      text: 0
    },
    {
      name: "decimal",
      text: "."
    }
  ];

  const rightDiv = [
    {
      name: "multiply",
      text: "x"
    },
    {
      name: "subtract",
      text: "-"
    },
    {
      name: "add",
      text: "+"
    },
    {
      name: "equals",
      text: "="
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="outer-div" className="outer-div">
        <div className="store-display">{storeArr}</div>
        <div id="display" className="display">
          {activeKey}
        </div>

        <div className="left-right">
          <div id="left-div" className="left-div">
            <div className="top-funcs">
              {topFuncs.map((i) => (
                <button
                  id={i.name}
                  className="btn"
                  key={i.text}
                  onClick={() => {
                    if (i.text === "AC") {
                      return clear();
                    } else {
                      click(i.text);
                    }
                  }}
                >
                  {i.text}
                </button>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div id="nums-div">
              {numsDiv.map((i) => (
                <button
                  id={i.name}
                  className="btn"
                  key={i.text}
                  onClick={() => {
                    click(i.text);
                  }}
                >
                  {i.text}
                </button>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="right-div" className="right-div">
            {rightDiv.map((i) => (
              <button
                id={i.name}
                className="btn"
                key={i.text}
                onClick={() => {
                  if (i.text === "=") {
                    calculate();
                  } else {
                    click(i.text);
                  }
                }}
              >
                {i.text}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i tried console logging but nothing shows on the console one the button is clicked

TypeError

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

but that literally makes no sense to me, it doesnt understand what .length means?

i tried console logging but nothing shows on the console one the button is clicked

TypeError

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

but that literally makes no sense to me, it doesnt understand what .length means?

i tried console logging but nothing shows on the console one the button is clicked

TypeError

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

but that literally makes no sense to me, it doesnt understand what .length means?

i tried console logging but nothing shows on the console one the button is clicked

TypeError

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

but that literally makes no sense to me, it doesnt understand what .length means?

i tried console logging but nothing shows on the console one the button is clicked

TypeError

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

but that literally makes no sense to me, it doesnt understand what .length means?

i tried console logging but nothing shows on the console one the button is clicked

TypeError

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

but that literally makes no sense to me, it doesnt understand what .length means?

Comment: It understands .length but you are asking the length of something that has no length.

Comment: You seem to be stuck in a loop of continually repeating your question.  This loop is occupying your I/O thread and preventing you from moving on to the next step of debugging the code.  Whatever is causing this will need to be fixed before you can even start to address anything in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadowing a variable is an error waiting to happen.  Which is exactly what you're doing here:

```
function calculate(storeArr) {
```

Within the scope of that function, `storeArr` doesn't refer to the state value.  It refers to the argument passed to the function.  And what argument do you pass to the function?  Nothing at all:

```
onClick={() => {
  if (i.text === "=") {
    calculate(); // <--- here
  } else {
    click(i.text);
  }
}}
```

So within the function, `storeArr` is `undefined`.  And, exactly as the error is telling you, you can't read a property from `undefined`.

**Edit: Don't Mutate State Either**

I just noticed that within your `calculate` function you are *modifying* the array.  Never mutate state in React.  So in this case it sounds like you need to:

1. Actually pass a value to your function.
2. Pass that value as a new array, *not* the existing state value.
3. Rename the local variable in the function, since it's confusing you.

So call the function with the new array:

```
onClick={() => {
  if (i.text === "=") {
    calculate([...storeArr]); // <--- here
  } else {
    click(i.text);
  }
}}
```

(Additionally, at least for future readers, also make sure that if this is an array of *objects* that you don't mutate any of the objects in the new array, since they're the same object references back to state.  *Deep cloning* arrays/objects is another matter altogether.)

And give the local variable a different name:

```
function calculate(sArr) {
```

And, of course, update all references within the function to the new local variable and not the state variable.

As an added improvement, since the function relies only on what is passed to it and not on component state, move the function outside of the component.  It can be its own module, or just outside the component within the same module.  This will further avoid confusion as it makes it more clear that the function is usable in isolation and not dependent on component state.

---

*Original Answer:*

Don't shadow the variable:

```
function calculate() {
```

That way within the function you're referring to the state value, not a local variable.  And you can then remove the unnecessary argument from other uses of the function.  So this:

```
console.log(calculate(storeArr));
```

Can become this:

```
console.log(calculate());
```

After all, why would you need to pass a value to a function which already exists within the same scope and can already access that value?

If you *do* want to pass a value to the function, give the function's local variable(s) a different name than one you're already using.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because your `calculate` function expects one argument, but you're not passing it anything in your `onClick` handler:

```
onClick={() => {
                  if (i.text === "=") {
                    calculate();
                  } else {
                    click(i.text);
                  }
                }}
```

This causes the `storeArr` argument in the `calculate` function to equal `undefined`, so then when you try iterating over it in the for loop, it throws an error because you can't access the `.length` property on an undefined value.